# cUrl calling custom URL protocols?

Tags: php, curl

I have wondered if cUrl supports custom URL protocols to be called, since I cannot find this in their documentation or perhaps just missed it?

Reason for the need is that I'm working on a web based system that will have to communicate with a device connected over bluetooth, this will be handled with other code but I now need to make sure that cUrl is capable of doing this. I don't wish to use javascript for this, done it before that way and it's not going to work in our current senario.

Many thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: The cURL documentation is actually really extensive. It mostly has examples in c but the API is basically the same for php https://curl.haxx.se/docs/

Comment: Can you give more information on the custom URL protocol you want to access ?

Comment: @forevergenin It's custom written, it's an installed protocol that can be used, it will just run local scripts that are defined by a custom registry.